# COM DLL was unloaded with lock counter is still non-zero

Tags: dll, com, atl

I have my program being instrumented by VSTS VSinstr tool, in order to collect the coverage information. But while running my instrumented binaries, specifically one of my COM dll, my program crashes at the exit point all the time.

I debug to find out that the crash is caused by:

- firstly, I load my COM dll with coLoadLibrary( bAutoFree = TRUE ).
- my program do some work.
- came to exit point.
- And then, my COM dll is unloaded. WINDBG indicates the its DllMain is called with dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH.
- code in my COM dll is executed and raise access violation ( code c0000005 ). what make me confused is, at this time, the value of _AtlModule.m_nLockCnt is still equal to 2!

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you calling CoLoadLibrary instead of CoCreateInstance?  Are you calling CoFreeLibrary?

Answer (score 0):

In order to query whether it is safe to unload a DLL loaded through through COM API, DLL's [`DllCanUnloadNow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is called. This is where you can set a break point and check if your COM DLL approves the unload (while still supposedly being busy with some background activity).

Comment: I think it is just because dll should be unloaded while the process is going to terminate, even its lock counter is not equal to 0.